# How do I implement this state-space model into GEKKO? (Not trying to solve the state-space model, but it is a part of an optimization)

Tags: python, python-3.x, gekko

I am looking for the value of `kx1, cx1, kz1, cz1, kx23, cx23, kz23, and cz23` that satisfy these equations. Below is the main equation for `T1` which is affected by `kx1, cx1, kz1, cz1`.

```
T1x = kx1 * (x + x2_1) + cx1 * (dx + dx2_1)   
T1z = kz1 * (z - z2_1) + cz1 * (dz + dz2_1)
T1  = np.sqrt(T1x**2 + T1z**2)
```

where:

```
x2_1 = r*(1 - np.cos(np.radians(rty)))
z2_1 = r*np.sin(np.radians(rty))
     
dx2_1 = r*np.sin(np.radians(rty))*np.radians(drty)
dz2_1 = r*np.cos(np.radians(rty))*np.radians(drty)*(-1)
```

Similiarly, this is the equation for `T2`.

```
T23x = kx23 * (x - x2_23) + cx23 * (dx + dx2_23)
T23z = kz23 * (z + z2_23) + cz23 * (dz + dz2_23)
T23  = np.sqrt(T23x**2 + T23z**2)
```

where:

```
x2_23 = r23*(1 - np.cos(np.radians(rty)))
z2_23 = r23*np.sin(np.radians(rty))
    
dx2_23 = r23*np.sin(np.radians(rty))*np.radians(drty)
dz2_23 = r23*np.cos(np.radians(rty))*np.radians(drty)*(-1)
```

The objective is to find `kx1, cx1, kz1, cz1, kx23, cx23, kz23, and cz23` that yields

```
T1  = T_max_1   # T_max_1 is a given value
T23 = T_max_23  # Similiarly, T_max_23 is also a given value
```

`r` and `r23` is also a given value.

The part that I am confused about is that `x, z, rty, dx, dz, drty` are part of the solution of a differential equation solved through state-space model that could be defined as seen below:

```
[ mot2 == mot.dt(),
  t_mass * mot2.dt() + damp * mot2 + k_stiff * mot == F ]
```

where `mot` is a (6x1) array that represents the motion matrix (x, y, z, rtx, rty, rtz). The size for `t_mass, damp, k_stiff` is (6x6), but the size for `F` is (6x1). And in this case, part of `damp` and `k_stiff` is affected by `kx1, cx1, kz1, cz1, kx23, cx23, kz23, and cz23` by these relations:

```
k_stiff[0,0] += kx1 + 2 * kx23
k_stiff[2,2] += kz1 + 2 * kz23

damp[0,0] += cx1 + 2 * cx23
damp[2,2] += cz1 + 2 * cz23
```

So far, I used GEKKO with these code:

```
gek = GEKKO(remote=False)

max_time_sim = 1600                         # max simulation time

delta_t = 0.01                              # space sample of time (default step)
t_n = max_time_sim/delta_t                  

t = np.linspace(0,max_time_sim,int(t_n))    # time axis

g = 9.81                                    # gravity acceleration m/s^2

t_steady = 800

gek.time = t


H = Tension[i-1,0]
T = Tension[i-1,1]
T_max_1     = Tension[i-1,2]      # kN
T_max_23    = Tension[i-1,3]      # kN
T_max       = T_max_1 + 2 * T_max_23
    
t_mass   = mass_def(T)
c_damp   = damp_def(T)
ampphase = force_def(T)

def Fext(t):
    Fh = np.array([   [H/2*ampphase[0,0]*np.cos(2*pi/T*t + ampphase[0,1])],   
                      [H/2*ampphase[1,0]*np.cos(2*pi/T*t + ampphase[1,1])],   
                      [H/2*ampphase[2,0]*np.cos(2*pi/T*t + ampphase[2,1])],  
                      [H/2*ampphase[3,0]*np.cos(2*pi/T*t + ampphase[3,1])],   
                      [H/2*ampphase[4,0]*np.cos(2*pi/T*t + ampphase[4,1])],   
                      [H/2*ampphase[5,0]*np.cos(2*pi/T*t + ampphase[5,1])]   ])
    return Fh
          
    
#%% moor iteration
    
# mooring variables
kx1  = gek.Var(value=1.0, lb=0.0)
cx1  = gek.Var(value=1.0, lb=0.0)
kz1  = gek.Var(value=1.0, lb=0.0)
cz1  = gek.Var(value=1.0, lb=0.0)
kx23 = gek.Var(value=1.0, lb=0.0)
cx23 = gek.Var(value=1.0, lb=0.0)
kz23 = gek.Var(value=1.0, lb=0.0)
cz23 = gek.Var(value=1.0, lb=0.0)
   
k_stiff  = np.asarray(stiff).copy()
k_stiff[0,0] += kx1.VALUE + 2 * kx23.VALUE
k_stiff[2,2] += kz1.VALUE + 2 * kz23.VALUE
    
damp = np.asarray(c_damp).copy()
damp[0,0] += cx1.VALUE + 2 * cx23.VALUE
damp[2,2] += cz1.VALUE + 2 * cz23.VALUE
    
F = Fext(t)
   
# motion eq. variables
mot  = gek.Array(gek.Var, (6,1), value=0.0)
mot2 = gek.Array(gek.Var, (6,1), value=0.0)
    
x    = mot[0,0]
z    = mot[2,0]
rty  = mot[4,0]
dx   = mot2[0,0]
dz   = mot2[2,0]
drty = mot2[4,0]
    
# constraints
gek.Equations([kx1 >= kx23, cx1 >= cx23,
                   kz1 >= kz23, cz1 >= cz23])
    
gek.Equations([x >= -6.0, x <= 6.0])
    
# state-space model
gek.Equations([mot2 == mot.dt(),
               t_mass * mot2.dt() + damp * mot2 + k_stiff * mot == F ])
    
# moor eq.
## moor 1
x2_1 = r*(1 - np.cos(np.radians(rty)))
z2_1 = r*np.sin(np.radians(rty))
     
dx2_1 = r*np.sin(np.radians(rty))*np.radians(drty)
dz2_1 = r*np.cos(np.radians(rty))*np.radians(drty)*(-1)
     
T1x = kx1 * (x + x2_1) + cx1 * (dx + dx2_1)   
T1z = kz1 * (z - z2_1) + cz1 * (dz + dz2_1)
T1  = np.sqrt(T1x**2 + T1z**2)
    
## moor 2 & 3
x2_23 = r23*(1 - np.cos(np.radians(rty)))
z2_23 = r23*np.sin(np.radians(rty))
    
dx2_23 = r23*np.sin(np.radians(rty))*np.radians(drty)
dz2_23 = r23*np.cos(np.radians(rty))*np.radians(drty)*(-1)
     
T23x = kx23 * (x - x2_23) + cx23 * (dx + dx2_23)
T23z = kz23 * (z + z2_23) + cz23 * (dz + dz2_23)
T23  = np.sqrt(T23x**2 + T23z**2)

gek.Equations([round(T1, 4) == round(T_max_1, 4), round(T23, 4) == round(T_max_23, 4)])
    
# objective
gek.options.SOLVER = 1
gek.solve(disp=False)
    
optimized = np.reshape(np.array([kx1.value, cx1.value, kz1.value, cz1.value,
                                 kx23.value, cx23.value, kz23.value, cz23.value,]), (1,8))
```

I expect this would yield `kx1, cx1, kz1, cz1, kx23, cx23, kz23, and cz23` that results in `T1 = T_max_1` & `T23 = T_max_23` while also keep the `x` part of the differential equation's result to be between `-6 <= x <= 6`. But, `.dt()` does not work on array when I write it like this.

How do I write the state-space equations with GEKKO? Is it possible to make it similiar to the equation below?

```
 [ 1 0 ] [ mot2     ] + [ 1 0 ] [ 0   ] + [ 1 0 ] [ 0   ] = [ mot.dt() ] 
 [ 0 m ] [mot2.dt() ]   [ 0 C ] [mot2 ]   [ 0 K ] [ mot ]   [ Fext(t)  ]
#(12x12) (12x1)         (12x12) (12x1)    (12x12) (12x1)    (12x1)   ----> matrix size
```

where 1 represents a (6x6) diagonal matrix with value 1 in its diagonal, 0 represents (6x6) matrix full of zeroes, and `m, C, K` is (6x6) matrix which would then be filled with `t_mass, damp, k_stiff`. And `Fext(t)` are time functions of force that is a (6x1) matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gekko` functions such as `m.sin()`, `m.cos()`, and `m.sqrt()` instead of the `numpy` versions of those functions.

```py
x2_1 = r*(1 - m.cos(np.radians(rty)))
z2_1 = r*m.sin(np.radians(rty))
     
dx2_1 = r*m.sin(np.radians(rty))*np.radians(drty)
dz2_1 = r*m.cos(np.radians(rty))*np.radians(drty)*(-1)
     
T1x = kx1 * (x + x2_1) + cx1 * (dx + dx2_1)   
T1z = kz1 * (z - z2_1) + cz1 * (dz + dz2_1)
T1  = m.sqrt(T1x**2 + T1z**2)
```

The `.dt()` operator is applied to scalar values, not arrays. A list comprehension is one way to define multiple equations with a single line of code.

```py
#gek.Equations([mot2 == mot.dt(),
#               t_mass * mot2.dt() + damp * mot2 + k_stiff * mot == F ])
gek.Equations([mot2[i]==mot[i].dt() for i in range(6)])
gek.Equations([t_mass*mot2[i].dt()+damp[i]*mot2[i]+k_stiff*mot[i]==F for i in range(6)])
```

A more effective method for adding constraints on `x` is to use an upper and lower bound.

```py
#gek.Equations([x >= -6.0, x <= 6.0])
x.LOWER=-6
x.UPPER=6
```

Gekko also doesn't have support for the `round()` function. There are integer values that can be declared with `m.Var(integer=True)`, but there are no methods to truncate the numbers during the optimization or simulation.

One other suggestion is that `.VALUE` only sets an initial guess for that variable. If you need to define a symbolic equation relationship between these variables, then drop the `.VALUE`.

```py
k_stiff  = np.asarray(stiff).copy()
k_stiff[0,0] += kx1.VALUE + 2 * kx23.VALUE
k_stiff[2,2] += kz1.VALUE + 2 * kz23.VALUE
    
damp = np.asarray(c_damp).copy()
damp[0,0] += cx1.VALUE + 2 * cx23.VALUE
damp[2,2] += cz1.VALUE + 2 * cz23.VALUE
```

Here is an example of a [double inverted pendulum](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DoubleInvertedPendulum) that may be a source of help for your project.

[image: double inverted pendulum]

```py
import math
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

#Defining a model
m = GEKKO(remote=True)

#################################
#Define initial and final conditions and limits
pi = math.pi;
x0 = 0; xdot0 = 0
q10 = pi; q1dot0 = 0 #0=vertical, pi=inverted
q20 = pi; q2dot0 = 0 #0=vertical, pi=inverted
xf = 0; xdotf = 0
q1f = 0; q1dotf = 0
q2f = 0; q2dotf = 0
xmin = -2; xmax = 2
umin = -10; umax = 10

#Defining the time parameter (0, 1)
N = 100
t = np.linspace(0,1,N)
m.time = t

#Final time
TF = m.FV(12,lb=2,ub=25); TF.STATUS = 1
end_loc = len(m.time)-1
final = np.zeros(len(m.time))
for i in range(N):
    if i >=(N-2):
        final[i] = 1000

#final[end_loc] = 100
final = m.Param(value=final)

#Parameters
mc = m.Param(value=1) #cart mass
m1 = m.Param(value=.1) #link 1 mass
m2 = m.Param(value=.1) #link 2 mass
L1 = m.Param(value=.5) #link 1 length
LC1 = m.Param(value=.25)  #link 1 CM pos
L2 = m.Param(value=.5) #link 1 length
LC2 = m.Param(value=.25) #link 1 CM pos
I1 = m.Param(value=.01) #link 1 MOI
I2 = m.Param(value=.01) #link 2 MOI
g = m.Const(value=9.81) #gravity
Bc = m.Const(value=.5) #cart friction
B1 = m.Const(value=.001) #link 1 friction
B2 = m.Const(value=.001) #link 2 friction

#MV
u = m.MV(lb=umin,ub=umax); u.STATUS = 1

#State Variables
x, xdot, q1, q1dot, q2, q2dot = m.Array(m.Var, 6)

x.value = x0; xdot.value = xdot0
q1.value = q10; q1dot.value = q1dot0
q2.value = q20; q2dot.value = q2dot0
x.LOWER = xmin; x.UPPER = xmax

#Intermediates
h1 = m.Intermediate(mc + m1 + m2)
h2 = m.Intermediate(m1*LC1 + m2*L1)
h3 = m.Intermediate(m2*LC2)
h4 = m.Intermediate(m1*LC1**2 + m2*L1**2 + I1)
h5 = m.Intermediate(m2*LC2*L1)
h6 = m.Intermediate(m2*LC2**2 + I2)
h7 = m.Intermediate(m1*LC1*g + m2*L1*g)
h8 = m.Intermediate(m2*LC2*g)

M = np.array([[h1, h2*m.cos(q1), h3*m.cos(q2)],
              [h2*m.cos(q1), h4, h5*m.cos(q1-q2)],
              [h3*m.cos(q2), h5*m.cos(q1-q2), h6]])
C = np.array([[Bc, -h2*q1dot*m.sin(q1), -h3*q2dot*m.sin(q2)],
              [0, B1+B2, h5*q2dot*m.sin(q1-q2)-B2],
              [0, -h5*q1dot*m.sin(q1-q2)-B2, B2]])

G = np.array([0, -h7*m.sin(q1), -h8*m.sin(q2)])
U = np.array([u, 0, 0])
DQ = np.array([xdot, q1dot, q2dot])
CDQ = C@DQ
b = np.array([xdot.dt()/TF, q1dot.dt()/TF, q2dot.dt()/TF])
Mb = M@b

#Defining the State Space Model
m.Equations([(Mb[i] == U[i] - CDQ[i] - G[i]) for i in range(3)])
m.Equation(x.dt()/TF == xdot)
m.Equation(q1.dt()/TF == q1dot)
m.Equation(q2.dt()/TF == q2dot)

m.Obj(final*(x-xf)**2)
m.Obj(final*(xdot-xdotf)**2)
m.Obj(final*(q1-q1f)**2)
m.Obj(final*(q1dot-q1dotf)**2)
m.Obj(final*(q2-q2f)**2)
m.Obj(final*(q2dot-q2dotf)**2)

#Try to minimize final time
m.Obj(TF)

m.options.IMODE = 6 #MPC
m.options.SOLVER = 3 #IPOPT
m.solve()

m.time = np.multiply(TF, m.time)

print('Final time: ', TF.value[0])

print(q1dot.value)
```